# Log and inspect objects and arrays with Karma and Jasmine and Angular 2

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run tests in Angular 2, and would like to log some of the stuff to the console so I can see what it actually is. Looking through blogs and documentation show me I should do things like:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
elm = fixture.nativeElement;
```

but what does that even mean? I would like to be able to log 'fixture' and inspect it but I only get [object Object]. when I use console.dir() it shows me that it's an object or array with a dropdown arrow, but clicking the arrow doesn't do anything. I used the debugger to see what I needed but logging is just easier for what I'm trying to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you get when you try to log arbitrary *objects*.

If you learn to read (API) documentation, you don't need to log this stuff. Here is the [API Reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/). Just type in what you what. For example check out [`TestBed`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html). Look at its method [`createComponent`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/TestBed-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor). It shows the method signature as returning a `ComponentFixture`. So that is the return type. So go [search for that](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/testing/index/ComponentFixture-class.html). It should show you all the methods on the `ComponentFixture`.